# Time Series Modeling Question

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, panel-data, volatility

I am trying to model the effect of volume traded on implied volatility of weekly options. I have the data for 52 weekly expiries at 5 minute intervals.

However the key insight is that each weekly run is a unique path which "is/may" be correlated to previous observations in same expiry path. In that case - each of these observations is not independent.

However this also does not fit the "panel" data. The same "individual/object" is not observed repeatedly. How should one go about modeling this?